Laravel (v10.45.1) collection unique method doesn't work expectedly
$oldValidUserPremiumPacks->unique('user_id')->pluck('user_id');

Thle line above gives me unique user ids but the line below doesn't:
$oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id')->unique('user_id');

I wonder why.

$oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id') returns an Collection of an array like [1, 2, 3], so ->unique('user_id') wouldn't work. It works the other way around since ->unique('user_id') returns a Collection of an array like [['user_id' => 1], ['user_id' => 2]], so ->pluck('user_id') would work.

Maybe try without a selecting field on unique?
$oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id')->unique();

The contents of $oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id') is: [1, 1, 2, 3]
Therefor $oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id')->unique('user_id') is trying to grab 1->user_id which doesn't work because 1 is an integer, not an object or array.
The contents of $oldValidUserPremiumPacks->unique('user_id') is: [['user_id' => 1], ['user_id' => 2]].
Aww, @TimLewis beat me to it.

Credit is all yours, I posted as a comment (hadn't verified yet), you correctly posted as an answer, so you beat me to it

Strangely $oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id')->unique(); doesn't work expectedly either, it gives me all user ids in the collection, not only unique ones.

@AdemTepe Could you print out the value of $oldValidUserPremiumPacks->pluck('user_id')? And the outputs of all the other variations you have tried and add it to your question? And possibly the value of $oldValidUserPremiumPacks? Then we can actually attempt to reproduce the issue with your exact data.

Sorry, my bad, it does. When I saw the last index, I thought it brought all user ids, but then I checked count of array, it was count of unique user ids as expected, therefore I get that unique() method doesn't reindex the array but keep indexes.
